# How to find out in a batch file if current user belongs to a specific user group?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use a batch file at startup of users to activate things like registry edits and map networked drives.

In this batch file I would like to include a command block that runs a certain command only for users being member of a specific user group.

Looking around does not really help and I don't have domain logins. So it needs to work with local logins.

Comment: You mean if the user in specific group? or he has admin rights?

Comment: @kgimpel Yes. I have created a user group myself, it's called 'Staff'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler way of doing this, but it works.

This looks up the current user and detects whether they're part of the Staff group and runs a command if they are.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%a in ('whoami') do net user %%a | find /i "Staff" >nul && echo run your command
```